# client side custom validator

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do client side custom validation. I have the following code in my aspx page, but I keep getting an error saying

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'chkList_Counts'
>   referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'validationCheck'
>   cannot be validated. at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String
>   name, String propertyName) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at

I cannot even see my page. I get the error right away before the page displays.

Below is my code

```
   <div> 
          <asp:Panel ID="panel3" runat="server" CssClass="cis_edit_pnl" 
              GroupingText="Counts" Width="1240px"> 
              <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList_Counts" runat="server" 
                   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                   RepeatColumns="3" Width="1060px"> 
              </asp:CheckBoxList> 
               <asp:CustomValidator ID="validationCheck" runat="server" ControlToValidate="chkList_Counts" ClientValidationFunction="check_checkBoxList" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="At least one of the check boxes should be checked"> 
                </asp:CustomValidator> 
         </asp:Panel> 
  </div>
```

and my javascript function is like this

```
    function check_checkBoxList(sender, args) { 
        debugger; 
        if (check_Counts() == false) { 
            args.IsValid = false; 
            return; 
        } 
        args.IsValid = true; 
        return; 
    } 

 function check_casrepCounts() { 
        var control; 
        control = document.getElementById("<%=chkList_Counts.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("input"); 
        if (eval(control)) { 

            for (var i = 0; i < control.length; i++) { 
                if (control[i].checked == true) 
                    return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/19/How-to-add-a-required-validator-to-a-CheckBoxList.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine now, I just had to remove controlToValidate and it worked.